# React cant uncheck checkbox selected by default

Tags: reactjs

I have a component, which renders checkbox and text field next to it. I pass a prop "defaultChecked" which decides that checkbox should be checked by default or not. If it's checked i can not uncheck it by click, what am i doing wrong? I need [isChecked] dependency in useEffect hook

```
const InputOptional = ({ id, content, name, isParams, setFormMainData, removeFormMainData, setFormParamsData, removeFormParamsData, defaultChecked }) => {
  const checkboxId = COMPONENT_TYPES.checkbox + id
  const [isValue, setValue] = useState(content)
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (defaultChecked) {
      setChecked(true)
    }

    isChecked && isValue !== null
    && (!isParams
      ? setFormMainData(ToolsClass.toFormObject(name, isValue))
      : setFormParamsData( ToolsClass.toFormObject(name, isValue) ))

  }, [isChecked])

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }
  const handleCheck = () => {
    isChecked && isValue !== null
    && (!isParams
      ? removeFormMainData(name)
      : removeFormParamsData(name)
    )
    setChecked(!isChecked)
  }
  return (
    <div style={wrapperStyle}>
      <StyledInput id={id} autocomplete='on' name={id} placeholder={ isValue } onChange={ handleChange } value={isChecked ? isValue : ''} disabled={isChecked ? false : true}/>
      <StyledCheckbox id={checkboxId} name={checkboxId} type={COMPONENT_TYPES.checkbox} onChange={ handleCheck } checked={isChecked}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should always use the same value for the checkbox, but for the reverse, simply add the following snippet to the `handleChange` property.

```
handleChange:function(event){
this.setState({selected: !this.state.selected});
```

Comment: not quite sure where it have to be added, would you include my code with this change please?

Comment: ' <StyledCheckbox id={checkboxId} name={checkboxId} type={COMPONENT_TYPES.checkbox} onChange=>{handleCheck (e.target.checked)}/>'

Comment: If you create a handlecheck function, just use the code. try if you want

Comment: but i have handleCheck function already with some logic

Comment: figured this out already, thx